# ReactiveUI Advantages of putting WhenAnyValue in constructor

Tags: system.reactive, reactiveui

I have noticed that many of the examples of the ReactiveUI extension methods are placed in the constructor.

What are the advantages of this over placing in a "SetupObservables" method?

Comment: it all depends when "SetupObservables" itself is called. If this is called directly or indirectly from the constructor then there is no difference. If you have more complex lifecycle requriements then it is another matter.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The advantage is that you should really only be calling RxUI methods like WhenAny when the object is created. You want to declare up front what *will happen* when certain events occur in a Declarative way.

This is a Different Way Of Thinking than any other MVVM framework, you want to describe *how things are related* as how your object works, and let RxUI itself deal with the updates. The best place to do that is in the constructor.

Comment: I'm with brad on this, in my experience the constructor rarely turns out to be ideal placement. I tend to just store injected dependencies in the ctor and do initialization/activation elsewhere.